# CUDA 5.5 - Relocatable device code causes unresolved external symbol

Tags: cuda

I'm using CUDA 5.5 and my compiler is VC2012. My projects consists of 2 .cu files. I need to use dynamic parallelism so I have enabled "Generate relocatable device code" option. As soon as this option is enabled I get the following linking error:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __fatbinwrap_54_tmpxft_0000110c_00000000_8_cuda_device_runtime_cpp1_ii_5f6993ef`

If I turn that option off the error disappears. The error does not depend on the contents of the files - if I comment out everything in them (`#if 0 .... #endif` so that they are essentially empty files) I still get the same error.

**Update:** I installed VC2010, and I still get the exact same error message! 
**Update 2:** I got really tired with this whole thing so I took a dynamic parallelism sample project from VC2010 from the SDK samples (cdpSimplePrint), replaced the files in it and compiled. The issue is gone. Tried to compare the settings between the two projects, but I couldn't find anything. **I don't know what caused it**, but frankly, at this stage I don't care already, as long as I have a workaround.

Comment: are you linking with correct version of CUDART?

Comment: @Ivan Solntsev
How would I go about checking that?

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are linking with the cudadevrt library, see the "Compiling and Linking" section in the [CUDA Dynamic Parallelism Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Dynamic_Parallelism_Programming_Guide.pdf) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I've added -lcudadevrt to nvlink in the project properties. Before I did there were more unresolved symbols. The link error above is not from the CUDA linker, but from the VC linker.

Comment: I get the following linking error when trying that:

cudadevrt.lib(cuda_device_runtime.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in kernel.cu.obj

I looked in the release notes (https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_55RC.pdf) and it says nothing about cudadevrt and VC2012. It does talk about some problems with the static version of the cudart library cudart.lib in VC2012 though. Do you think this is related?

Comment: Do you have VS2010 installed as well as VS2012? Can you check that both the CUDA compile/link step and the C++ compiler/link step are picking up the same version? I don't have VS2012 but in earlier versions you could select which toolchain to use, VC11 == _MSC_VER 1700 == VS2012.

Comment: If you are building the debug version of the project, try building release version instead and see if the results are any different (as far as the VC link error goes.)  In CUDA 5.5 RC, only the (VS2010) *release* version of the static cudart library is included, I'm not sure if the same applies to the device cudart library.  I would also add `--cudart=shared` as an nvcc switch, if it's not already specified, although I don't think it bears on this specific issue.

Comment: @Tom: I only have VC2012 installed, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: Same thing happens in all versions (Debug/Release, 32/64). I tried adding `--cudart=shared` before, it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: Well, I installed VC2010, and I still get the same error message, so this is not a VC2012 related issue.
I'm totally lost here...